# Got wrong height from getMeasureHeight() of ListView item in Android M

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have to measure item in `ListView`, and it works well except Android M.
In android M, I got wrong height of item (not equal to viewHeight) from `convertView.getMeasureHeight()`.

```
int viewWidthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(viewWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int viewHeightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(viewHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
convertView.measure(viewWidthSpec, viewHeightSpec);
```

Is it an issue from android M or any wrong using in my code?